# Java - Triggering a JPopupMenu to execute code when it is shown?

Tags: java, swing, listener, jpopupmenu

When a JPopupMenu appears i want to execute some code for it. I can't figure out what listener should i use to trigger when the JPopupMenu becomes visible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should register a property change listener.

```
JPopupMenu menu = new JPopupMenu();
menu.addPropertyChangeListener("visible", myPropertyChangeListener);
```

In the listener you should check whether the new value of the event is `Boolean.TRUE`.

Answer (score 1):

> what listener should i use to trigger when the JPopupMenu becomes visible!

In case you want the code to execute before the menu is visible so you can configure the popup you can add a `PopupMenuListener` to the `JPopup`. It supports 3 events:

1. popupMenuCanceled
2. popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible
3. popupMenuWillBecomeVisible